# if a sequence has a convergent subsequence, is it a Cauchy sequence in the norm?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose {$g_n$} has a convergent subsequence {$g_{n^k}$},how can we prove that {$g_n$} is a Cauchy sequence in the norm,I tried using triangle inequality but failed,the question is from stein's real analysis(chapter 4,lemma4.1)[image]

Comment: In general your assertion is not correct, take for example the sequence $(-1)^k$, it has two convergent subsequences, but does not converge itself. I think there is a misunderstanding in what the proof wants to say, i.e. I think the authors wants to say that for the theorem he wants to show, it is enough that a subsequence converges. Can you provide more background, i.e. what is the exact theorem?

Comment: Looks like the projection theorem...

Comment: @ Meowdog: I thought the same, but depending on what kind of norm or space you are dealing with, the proof can become quite different, for example it is easier, if we are in a Hilbertspace

Comment: @humanStampedistI reedit it already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comments, it is in general not correct, that if a sequence has a convergent subsequence, that it is convergent itself. Just take $(-1)^k$.

Furthermore this is not what the proof asserts. The author merely says, that if we would have a convergent subsequence of $g_n$, then we would already have a closest point $g_0$. Let me explain how this works:

Let $g_{n_k}$ be a convergent subsequence of $g_n$ and let us call the limit $g_0$. Since $\|f-g_n\|\rightarrow d$, this is also correct for all subsequences, hence
$$\|f-g_{n_k}\|\rightarrow d$$
On the other hand, the convergence of $g_{n_k}$ w.r.t. to the norm yields
$$\|f - g_{n_k}\|\rightarrow \|f-g_0\|.$$
Hence we have
$$\|f-g_0\| = d.$$
Since $S$ is closed, we also have $g_0\in S$. Hence $g_0$ is a closest point and the result would follow.

These kind of arguments can be quite powerful. For example it did not need, that $S$ is a subspace, just that it is closed. In other words, if you can somehow find such a convergent subsequence, you can find closest points also for more general $S$.